# express as a product of three factors $ x^4 + 3x^3 +4x^2 -6x -12 $

Tags: polynomials

express $ x^4 + 3x^3 +4x^2 -6x -12 $ as a product of three factors

i can't do it by means of synthetic division the factors are probably not integers but how else am i supposed to simplify it?

i input it in a calculator and got at most 2 factors $ (x^2 -2)(x^2 +3x +6) $ i know a quadratic expression can have two answers but i can reach this stage by normal means i wanna know what i have to do.

Comment: Since you are considering the possibility that the answer won't be all integers, can you factor $x^2-2$ as a difference of squares?

Comment: then it will be $ (x- \sqrt2)(x+ \sqrt2)(x^2 +3x +6) $  but i don't know how to get to  $ (x^2 -2)(x^2 +3x +6) $

Comment: ? You just answered your own question.

Comment: The general solution to a 4th degree polynomial is a very involved process.  I don't know if this one has a trick.  In general is it possible to find a solution to a biquadratic just like you would find it for a quadratic, but it's not a formula that's easy to memorize.

Comment: first, i didn't answered my own question i just stated again what i was looking for and that is, the means by which this $ x^4 + 3x^3 +4x^2 -6x -12 $ becomes this $ (x^2 -2)(x^2 +3x +6) $ from there, i can express the polynomial as three factors but then again i'm missing a step. second i normally would solve a polynomial with synthetic division but im not getting anything through it in this equation

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE: The OP is looking for a way to discover that factorization *without* using a calculator, I believe.

Comment: One method is to hope for a factorization of the form $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$.  Expand this out, equate coefficients with the given polynomial, and try to solve the resulting system for $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ using substitution.  If you run into a nasty polynomial to solve, try the rational root test.